# Rake::Tasks sources missed

Tags: rake

I just start using Rake instead of Make for building my projects, and would like to use some kind of "task template" for automating the building.

Consider the following snippets:

```
task :test1 => ['1', '2']
task :test2 => ['3', '4']
Rake::Tasks.each do |task|
    p task
    p task.sources
end
```

The output is:

```
$ rake
<Rake::Task test1 => [1, 2]>
[]
<Rake::Task test2 => [3, 4]>
[]
```

My question is why `task.sources` is `[]`, that is the prerequisites are missed? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The prerequisites of a task are accessed with `task.prerequisites`.
`task.sources` and `task.source`is only used for tasks that are built from a rule as described in the rdocs: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/rake/rdoc/Rake/Task.html#method-i-source